# YAML Plain value cannot start with directive indicator character %

Tags: list, yaml, jinja2

I'm trying to create a list in YAML that is parsed by jinja to be used in a for loop. I have the following line:

```
{%- set my_var = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] %}
```

And VSCode gives me the following error: "Plain value cannot start with directive indicator character %"

However when I have something like this:

```
{%- set my_var1 = [
   ('str1', '100'),
   ('str2', '200'),
   ('str3', '300')
] %}
```

I dont get any errors or warnings, I've tried searching for the error and can't seem to find any information, what is causing this error? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you selected *Jinja* for the syntax in VSCode and not *YAML*.

Processing this input as YAML *without* Jinja preprocessing is obviously a syntax error since it is not valid YAML.